# Swiper.js/React How to go to the last slide after creating a new one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, carousel, swiper.js

I'm working on a carousel with dynamic inputs. Users can add new columns and if there're more than 3 columns in total, only 3 should be visible. After adding a new column, it should scroll all the way down to the last element.

Originally I did this:

```
export default function App() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState([1, 1])
  const [swiper, setSwiper] = useState()
  const addValue = () => {
    setValues(prev => [...prev, 1])
    swiper?.slideTo(swiper.slides.length - 1)
  }
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={addValue}>add</button>
      <Swiper
        slidesPerView={3}
        spaceBetween={30}
        pagination={{
          clickable: true,
        }}
        modules={[Pagination]}
        className="mySwiper"
        onSwiper={setSwiper}
      >
        {values.map((_, index) => <SwiperSlide key={index}>Slide {index}</SwiperSlide>)}
      </Swiper>
    </>
  );
```

But then I realized that when scrolling to the end, the new column has not been created yet.

So I did this:

```
const addValue = async () => {
  setValues(prev => [...prev, 1])
  await swiper?.update()
  swiper?.slideTo(swiper.slides.length - 1)
}
```

This works fine in the code sandbox, but the project I'm working on has a lot of elements on each slide, and it becomes **very** slow when a new column is created when there are 5-6 in total, and even crashes sometimes.

[Code sandbox link for reference](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/swiper-react-slides-per-view-forked-2q69v8?file=/src/App.jsx:9,23)